# Create multiple Python wheels with Poetry

Tags: python, python-wheel, python-poetry

I would like to create a Python package that wraps functionality provided by a precompiled shared library. I think that the way to go is to create a wheel per OS (and architecture) and publish that. I haven't found a way to make Poetry output anything but `py3-none-any.whl` though.

Is there a way to achieve this with Poetry? Do I have to use `setup.py` instead? How do I make this work with either?